# how to make pug MIXIN "display flex"?

Tags: css, pug, mixins

Sry for bad eng but
I'm cant display my object inline
I'm just want to make it: `"1st product" "2nd product"  "3rd product"`
but my css just ignore it and do like:

```
                                       "1st product"
                                       "2nd product"
                                       "3rd product"
```

Pls help :(

Here's pug code

```
mixin category(data)
  .product-card
    a(href="/category/" + data.id)= data.name
    br
    img.cat-img(src= data.imageUrl)
```

And css

```
.product-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; 
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: white;
}
```

Comment: Flex container defaults to `flex-wrap: nowrap` so you need to make it `wrap`. Your flex items probably need width 100% so they can take the full row after the flex wrap is fixed

Comment: it's not working :(

Comment: `display: flex` needs to go on the parent container, not `.product-card`.